# How to read data from JOSN file with Angular Observable

Tags: typescript, angular9, angular14

I have a JSON file called `reportConfig`. I want read that data using angular and typescript.

Here I have added my JSON file

```
{
  "accessToken": "12345",
  "style": "color",
  "projection": "globe",
  "zoomLevel": 5
  "markerScale": 1.1
}
```

and created new class called `ConfigModel`

```
export class MapReportConfigModel {
  accesToken: string;
  style: string;
  projection: number;
  zoomLevel: number;
  markerScale: number;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  // read json data
  getMapConfig(): Observable<ReportConfigModel > {
    let configData = `assets/reportConfig.json`;
    return this.httpClient.get<ReportConfigModel>(configData );
  }
}
```

Now I have child component called `ReportContainer`. so my question is how can I call from child component to `getMapConfig()` method.

```
export class ReportContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private mapReportConfigModel: MapReportConfigModel
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  //load initial map
  loadMap(): void {

  }

  private getMapConfigData(): void {
    this.httpClient.get(this.mapReportConfigModel);
  }
}
```

I have tried this but don't know how to implement in correctly.

Could someone can help me to resolve this. from child component I want to call this method to get json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so my question is how can I call from child component to
> getMapConfig() method.

Subscribe to the Observable that you get from your `getMapConfig` method on the `mapReportConfigModel` private variable.

```
export class ReportContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(
    private mapReportConfigModel: MapReportConfigModel
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Invoke the dependency from your component
    this.mapReportConfigModel.getMapConfig().subscribe((result) => {
       console.log(result);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me an answer for this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75629532/how-to-install-maxbox-gl-to-angular-version-9-0-2-project