# How to install Maxbox GL to Angular version 9.0.2 project

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am working on angular version 9.0.2 project. I just want to add MapBox GL plugging to my application. I tried this command. Also I want to know using this command can I use typescript for mapbox.

```
npm install --save mapbox-gl
```

But when I tried to install it I got below mention error message.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/animations@9.1.9
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@9.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@9.2.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^9.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"9.0.2" from @angular/common@9.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@9.2.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!       @angular/cdk@"^9.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"9.0.2" from @angular/forms@9.0.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@"^9.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@6.1.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!         @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^6.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     6 more (@angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!   8 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"9.1.9" from @angular/animations@9.1.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^9.1.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@9.1.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"9.1.9" from @angular/animations@9.1.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^9.1.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Could someone can help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start is StackBlitz for this one:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I installed mapbox-gl on the above stack blitz without any errors.

I suggest nuking your node_modules folder with `rm -rf node_modules` and trying the command again `npm install --save mapbox-gl`

Comment: I just want to install it to my local machine. because of angular version 9 I won't be able to run it

Comment: I used this command npm config set legacy-peer-deps true. after that I was able to installed it. but I don't know the meaning of this command and why we use it. Do you have any idea about that. actually I am new to angular

Comment: As the error message says, `legacy-peer-deps` might present other problems when you run the app. "... to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution."

Comment: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.